# An intuitive limit: random variable divided by partial sum going almost surely to $0$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ be i.i.d. random variables. Assume that $\mathbb{E}X_{1}=\infty$ and let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$. Show that

$$\frac{X_{n}}{S_{n}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$$

Showing that this limit holds when $0\neq\mathbb{E}X_{1}<\infty$ is not too bad, but the case of an infinite mean is trickier. One can use Hewitt-Savage to show that the limit must be almost surely constant and then pass to distributional convergence to show that the constant is indeed $0$, however I would expect that there is a much simpler way to establish this limit.

How would you show this limit using "simple" techniques?

Comment: Is each $X_n$ almost surely finite?

Comment: @mathworker21 yes they are.